# Can users manipulate javascript to overwrite S3 crossdomain.xml?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, amazon-s3

I allow users to upload to s3 directly without the need to go through the server ; Everything works perfectly; my only worry is the security.

In my javascript code I check for file extensions . However I know in javascript code Users can manipulate script- in my case to allow upload of xml files - (since client side upload) and thus would'nt they be able to replace the crossdomain.xml in my bucket and accordingly be able to control my bucket?

Note: I am using the bucket owner access key and secret key.

**Update:**

Any possible approaches to overcome this issue...?

Comment: anyone can grab the client side code from your page and modify it to circumvent the xml check.

Comment: Any thoughts on how this should be tackled?

Comment: unless S3 allows you to run your code on their side, where you can check the contents of the files, you could post to your own server and do the check there and then post to S3 from your server.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but i do not think one can run code on s3 other than html; as for the server side processing I thought since i can directly upload to s3 I would save the server side processing time and resources for something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not adverse to running additional resources, you can accomplish this by running a [Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490).

Here's the gist:

- Your token vending machine (TVM) runs as a reduced privileged user.
- Your client code still uploads directly to S3, but it needs to contact your TVM to get temporary, user-specific token to access your bucket when the user logs in
- The TVM calls the [Amazon Security Token Service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html?r=7687) to create temporary credentials for your user to access S3
- The S3 API uses the temporary credentials when it makes requests to upload/download
- You can define [polices](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PoliciesOverview.html?r=3093) on your buckets to limit what areas of the bucket each user can access

A simple example of creating a "dropbox"-like service using per-user access is detailed [here](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367).

Comment: Will read on the info you posted; will get back to you ASAP...thank you